# error The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level.

Hello, when using mobile to test or nox emulator and even Android Studio emulator itself, it creates this error
I am very beginner, please help me

[image]

Comment: in your Gradle file check your minSdkVersion.it means that the devices that are lower than that sdk could not install your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element), **minSdkVersion** is:

> An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.

In other words as stated in [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd) article:

> The minSdkVersion is one of the signals the Google Play Store uses to determine which of a user’s devices an app can be installed on. It also plays an important role during development: by default lint runs against your project, warning you when you use any APIs above your minSdkVersion, helping you avoid the runtime issue of attempting to call an API that doesn’t exist. Checking the system version at runtime is a common technique when using APIs only on newer platform versions.

**Solution:**

You should use a device/emulator that is supported by your app's minSdk value. Alternatively, you can change the minimum sdk value that your app supports, but you shouldn't do that just to resolve such an error, you must have more reasons. You should choose the solution that serves your needs best.